# 2012 Mac Pro hard disks disabled after system spontaneously locked with a PIN code

Tags: macos, partitioning, gparted

(This was initially posted on reddit.com and shortly after on MacRumors)

```
Equipment:
Mac Pro (mid-2012) running macOS 10.14.6 Mojave all patches current
Processor 2x3.46 GHz 6-core Intel Xeon
Memory 48 GB
Graphics NVIDIA GeForce GTX 680 2GB
Boot disk 1TB NVME SSD
Five additional internal hard disks with a total of about 16 TB of available space
```

This is an extremely weird and unusual problem. Apologies for the long explanation.

I purchased this machine on Craigslist in May 2022, configured the system, and it had been running pretty much continuously without any apparent issues until about two weeks ago. At that time, the computer started emitting an alert with a beeping sound every five or ten minutes. When I checked the Mac Pro's screen, the entire window was gray with a message saying "Enter your system lock PIN code to unlock this Mac", and a six digit box below. I had no idea what had caused this, nor what the six digit code might be. (See a similar image to what I saw in the link below. BTW, this was NOT the Firmware Passcode screen with the Lock symbol.)  Note that I have never used FileVault, and it wasn't installed on this system at all.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7369612

The first thing that came to mind was a ransomware attack, but when I checked my email, there was none (I have received no ransomware notifications since). The next thing I thought of was that someone unknown to me had used Apple ID to remotely lock the machine, using "Find My". (The latter hypothesis still seems to be the best guess at what caused this issue.)

I tried a reboot (let's call this one Mac Pro A). Same thing. I tried holding down the Option key to bring up another internal partition disk, a bootable Carbon Copy Cloner backup, but all five of the additional internal disks were inaccessible, as well as each and every partition on each of these disks. I have a spare 2012 Mac Pro (let's call this Mac Pro B) with an additional internal bootable disk running Mojave. When I inserted the internal bootable disk from Mac Pro B into Mac Pro A and rebooted, the same PIN code message appeared on the entire window. When I inserted the hard disks from Mac Pro A into Mac Pro B and tried to boot from Mac Pro B, the hard disks originally in Mac Pro A were showing as inaccessible. I tried moving the CPU tray from Mac Pro A to Mac Pro B, and vice versa, but still no luck. It was pretty clear to me that the lock was on the chassis and not to the CPU tray. That is the serial number of the machine is tied to the chassis, and not to the CPU tray, and the PIN code is linked to the firmware in the chassis via the serial number of the machine.

One additional observation is that Mac Pro A with the correct serial number of the machine showed up in the Apple ID on another Mac computer I have, an iMac running macOS 10.13.6 High Sierra. (I mention the OS because iCloud and Find My Device appear to be slightly different on different macOS's, such as Catalina, Mojave, and High Sierra.) However in the web version of iCloud, Mac Pro A did NOT appear under "All Devices", neither green (online) nor gray (offline), although my other Mac devices, including computers, iPhone, and iPad did appear as one would expect.

I spent the next day on the phone with Apple Support, calling them three or four separate times. The first line support engineers were encouraging, but unfortunately they were not particularly helpful in resolving the issue. Of course both the 2012 Mac Pro and macOS 10.14 Mojave are out of support, so that didn't help matters. Also, since I did not have the purchase invoice of Mac Pro A, and the person I had purchased it from had also purchased it used. Neither did he have the purchase invoice (see the next paragraph).

At this point, I was not a happy camper. I still had the phone number of the person that I had purchased Mac Pro A from back in May, 2022, and contacted him. He is a Mac developer and seemed fairly knowledgeable re: computers. He assured me that he had removed Mac Pro A from his Apple ID. He immediately re-checked to confirm this.
One thing the former owner did provide was a six digit code, say it's 123456, which he said was his password and he said to try. When I entered this code, bang, the system rebooted and after a few minutes up popped my original Mac Pro A screen. I was delighted. However, after ten seconds or so, the system spontaneously rebooted, and presented the gray PIN code screen.

I tried everything I could think of, booting into single user mode, booting into recovery mode, turning off and on the Firmware Passcode. Nothing seemed to work.

I struggled with this off and on for about two weeks, unsuccessfully. Yesterday, a partial but significant breakthrough. I tried a fresh install of macOS 10.14.6 removing all the internal hard disks, including the bootable NVME, from Mac Pro A, inserting a bootable macOS 10.14 Mojave flash disk (originally from dosdude1) and a newly HFS+ formatted 500GB SSD. To my surprise, the macOS 10.14 installation proceeded except that when it came time to reboot, the system came up with another, different message: "Your computer is disabled. Try again in 1 minute." (See the image in the link below.)

After a Google search, I stumbled upon this gem:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/364269/your-computer-is-disabled-try-again-in-60-minutes

What is significant here for my purpose were the following commands:

```
nvram -c
nvram -xp
nvram -c
nvram -c
nvram -c
nvram -c
nvram -xp
```

I rebooted using the macOS 10.14 installer flash drive, typed the commands above into the Terminal app. Voila! the fresh macOS 10.14 installed on Mac Pro A continued to completion. I quickly checked that I could successfully reboot the freshly installed macOS 10.14 without the annoying PIN message(s) on Mac Pro A, and yes, I could.

I then shut down Mac Pro A, installed its original bootable NVME SSD, and it booted up without any issues, and it appeared nothing had been damaged. Yippee!

Unfortunately, and this is my remaining problem, when I inserted the original remaining hard disks--except for the NVME boot disk--none of them showed up on the desktop. Each of these hard disks shows up in Disk Utility, but all are inaccessible. Each of the disk partitions on each of the hard disks are greyed out, labelled "disk3s2", "disk2s3", "disk5s2", etc. They are unmountable from Disk Utility, For example, here is the Disk Utility output for one of them (each of the other disabled disks is similar):

```
disk3s2 480.13 GB
Not mounted
Used --
Free --
Mount Point: Not Mounted
Type: SATA Internal Physical Volume
Capacity: 480.13 GB
Owners: Disabled
Available: Zero KB
Connection: SATA
Used: --
Device: disk3s2
```

This morning I called Apple Support to see if they had any ideas. Again, they were sympathetic, but were unable to move me any further. They did set me up with a visit to the Genius Bar for Monday morning (it's Friday morning as I'm writing this) which I'm happy about.
If you've gotten to the bottom of this post, thanks, and again, sorry for the verbiage. I have tried to be as clear, concise and accurate as I could with the information I have.

I'm hoping there's someone out there who can help me recover my data, which has years and years of work.

As I mentioned earlier, I have an appointment tomorrow with the Genius Bar in the city where I live. I'm hopeful (what else can I say?) that the folks there can help me recover my TBs of data.

But if not, what then?

I'm surmising here that the issue is software related, and that there's a couple of bits that need to be flipped to get my data back, or some other such magic incantation. To do that I need something stronger than Apple provides with Disk Utility, diskutil, etc. I suppose what I need is a partition editor. That brings to mind gparted, the GNU partition editor. According to the website at gparted.org, gparted does handle data on x86-64 computers including OS X, so I'm presuming that includes HFS+.

Over the years, I've used gparted on UNIX computers, and Linux and Windows but never on macOS. It's a serious and trustworthy application, and it's free.

Anyone out there with expertise using gparted to manipulate partitions or recover data on macOS?

Comment: The first post you linked to is clearly talking about ransomware, the dodgy email address at the bottom of the screenshot is a dead giveaway. But you haven’t said if this was also present on the screen you saw. If you are able to confirm whether it was ransomware and if so what variant, it may increase the chance of recovery

Comment: So you trusted your *TBs of data* to a single machine without any backup strategy *and* that machine being a second or third hand computer more than a decade old computer bought from a stranger at Craigslist without even installing the OS from scratch? That's a bunch of no-nos pilling up...

Comment: @ChanganAuto Fortunately your assumptions are not completely accurate.  I did have a backup strategy, and most--but not all--of my data is backed up on other computers.  But, seriously, would YOU have made a plan to prevent ALL of your hard drives being erased simultaneously, which is what happened.  And this decade old computer, 2x6-core  @ 3.46 GHz for under $US 800 was too tempting for me to pass up (I have two others as well).  I don't regret the purchase at all; I certainly can't afford a new or even newish Mac Pro.

Comment: 1. A good backup is complete, versioned and tested to work whenever needed. And yes, I do have backups of everything important following the standard 3-2-1 rule: At least 3 copies in 2 different media and 1 off-site (cloud). 2. The older the hardware the more the chances of failure are, therefore backups are even more important, it's just statistics, I'm not saying it wasn't a good deal. 3. The main problem however was using it "as is", I would NEVER *not* nuke&pave (reinstall) a second hand machine from a stranger, I always reinstall even when they come from a known and trusted person.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Thanks, those are good points about doing backups.  And yes, older hardware does increase the chances for failure, and it's the tradeoff you make when you buy an older cheaper machine.  I happen to think these old Mac Pros are awesome.

However, I don't know where you got the idea that I didn't re-install the Mac Pro when I bought it in May 2022.  The one SSD that came with the machine purchased was formatted and used in another Mac Pro.  All six hard disks, including the NVME SSD boot disk were either purchased new or repurposed from other machines I owned.